# What is the difference between these two tables (catalog_product_entity_decimal and catalog_product_index_eav_decimal) in Magento?

Tags: magento

This table **catalog_product_index_eav_decimal** data seems to be generated after indexing process, if I am not wrong. So, which one should I use to fetch value of an attribute? I am using an attribute of *frontend_type* **price**.

Answer (score 0):

Magento use index table for speedup for example in cart page and checkout page Magento take value from index table.

If you want to get price then you can use below.

```
$_product->getPrice();
```

Comment: I do not want to fetch price. I want to fetch value of an attribute which is of type decimal. There is case where I have to put a join using any of the tables mentioned in my question but I am confused which one to use. This table **catalog_product_entity_decimal** will always have attribute entry and I am using this for now. However this table has 1 millions records where as **catalog_product_index_eav_decimal** has only 20k records. Therefore, I am not sure whether later one would give result every-time irrespective of indexing is done or not.

Comment: You no need to go through table, It would be great if you go through method . Make you sure that attribute First letter should be start with **capital**
`$_product->get[Your_attribute_name_here]`